# How to store client date time in db to match with server timezone in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have date and time html5 picker in client side.

When user selects date and time I am sending it to backend in the following format `2018-11-01T13:00`

In the backend it stores the date time as `2018-11-01T13:00:00+00` because the data type I defined column run_at as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. I read this value and store it in another table called schedule and again read it from schedule table to schedule the job.

But my problem is when I read the run_at from DB and store it in another table called schedule it saves as `2018-11-01T17:00:00+00` it adds +4 hours instead `2018-11-01T13:00:00+00`. It doesn't match with created at timestamp value.

How can I store run_at in another table that matches with server time zone?

I am not getting an idea how to store the run_at to match with server timezone. Please excuse me I can't post the code from my office laptop.

Comment: Use UTC datetime for this purpose.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more. I actually got stuck about where should I use UTC time zone and how to do that please

Comment: On both sides. Client and server. Client selects his local datetime and after submit, you convert it to UTC and send to server..

Comment: @bigless Thank you. Your comment is just awesome. I am able to fix the issue with new Date(requestData.runAt).toISOString();

Comment: @bigless Really that's huge help for me. Big thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear that